# Bash string eval unclear

Tags: bash

Consider the following in a bash script:

```
STOP_SEARCH_STR="'""for $TASKNAME""'"
echo $STOP_SEARCH_STR               # prints 'for Our Special Task_4'
echo "$STOP_SEARCH_STR"             # prints 'for Our Special Task_4'
echo "grep -F "$STOP_SEARCH_STR" "$TEMP"/draft" # prints grep -F 'for Our Special Task_4' /tmp/draft
echo "$(grep -F "$STOP_SEARCH_STR" "$TEMP"/draft)"  # prints nothing!
echo $("grep -F "$STOP_SEARCH_STR" "$TEMP"/draft")  # prints nothing!
```

And the following content in the $TEMP/draft text file:

```
2019-11-21 08:13:58,825 Task started: 'Our Special Task_4' of type 'Our - Special Task' 
2019-11-21 08:14:10,509 Task ended: 'Success' for Our Special Task_4 -- Elapsed time: 11.0 seconds
```

If I **manually** type the command `grep -F 'for Our Special Task_4' /tmp/draft`, I receive the second line in the draft text file:

```
2019-11-21 08:14:10,509 Task ended: 'Success' for Our Special Task_4 -- Elapsed time: 11.0 seconds
```

But the the last 2 commands above (inside a bash script) print nothing!

Any idea why?

Comment: @Jesse_b I am pretty sure you are right, but at the moment I have no clue how to fix this. Can you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: @datsb Remove the single-quotes from `STOP_SEARCH_STR`. They are being treated as part of the string to search for.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I did that. It makes matters worse: The command fails even when typed manually. It doesn't like the spaces in `for Our Special Task_4`.

Comment: That last command _ought_ to give you an error! There is no command named literally "`grep -F `".

Comment: @Kusalananda You are correct. See my comment to the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quotes aren't special after a variable is expanded.

Assuming `TASKNAME` contains `Our Special Task_4`, then `STOP_SEARCH_STR` is set to `'for Our Special Task_4'`, including those quotes. That's what your `echo` shows.

When you run `grep -F "$STOP_SEARCH_STR" "$TEMP"/draft`, you're giving `grep` the string `'for Our Special Task_4'` to look for. That string doesn't exist in the file, so no lines match, and `grep` prints nothing.

Remove the quotes, you're not looking for them:

```
task="Our Special Task_4"
str="for $task"
grep -F "$str" "$TEMP/draft"
```

Note: you **do** need the double quotes around the variable expansion `"$str"` or `"$STOP_SEARCH_STR"` to prevent word-splitting, see [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/170373)

When you **manually** type the command `grep -F 'for Our Special Task_4' /tmp/draft`, the quotes are part of the shell syntax and effectively remove the special meaning of the spaces within them. This is different from quotes inside a variable which act like ordinary characters.

---

As an aside: 1) `echo "$(somecmd)"` is usually redundant, you could just run `somecmd` directly. 2) Here: `echo $("grep -F "$STOP_SEARCH_STR" "$TEMP"/draft")`, because of how the quotes surround the whitespace, you're trying to run a command called `grep -F 'for`. You should probably get an error for that:

```
$ echo $("grep -F "$STOP_SEARCH_STR" "$TEMP"/draft")
bash: grep -F 'for: command not found
```

Comment: I was too quick to celebrate: I removed the quotes but now the command effectively becomes `grep -F for Our Special Task_4 /tmp/draft` which finds all lines with the word `for` in them but complains "No such file or directory" for the rest of the words in the search string (Our, Special, Task_4). How do I add quotes around the "string with spaces to be searched for" so that work as if the command is typed manually?

Comment: @datsb, what's the exact command you used?

Comment: The exact command is just as I originally posted, except that I removed the quotes. It's basically the same as `grep -F "$str" "$TEMP/draft"` that you suggested. I am now totally confused, although you explanation is excellent. Note that the challenge here is the spaces in the search string.

Comment: @datsb, yes, I know. As long as you have the double-quotes around the variable expansion, it should work fine. They're the quotes that **are** necessary. (I should have been explicit about that from the start.)

Comment: @datsb "Always double quote any expansion" is a simple rule of thumb that you could follow, and which will be correct more often that not.

Comment: see also: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting

Answer (score 1):

You should change this line:

```
STOP_SEARCH_STR="'""for $TASKNAME""'"
```

to this line (yes, no single quotes needed, they are not useful):

```
STOP_SEARCH_STR="for $TASKNAME"
```

And use this line in the script (yes, quoted as shown):

```
grep -F "$STOP_SEARCH_STR" "$TEMP"/draft
```

If you want/need to add an echo (which is superfluos and may even cause problems) use this line (yes, quote all the expansions (variables and subshell)):

```
echo "$(grep -F "$STOP_SEARCH_STR" "$TEMP"/draft")"
```

Comment: Thanks. @ilkkachu already helped me resolve my problem. But your answer further clarifies the issue and may help others in the future.